# Spring Config Client XML equivalent of @RefreshScope

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

We have an existing Spring MVC application (non Spring-boot application) with all (or most) of the beans configured in the XML. We wanted to use this as a Spring Cloud Config Client (we have a Spring Boot application acting as config server).

In this regard, what is the XML equivalent of configuring the beans in XML with refresh scope (same as @RefreshScope annotation). Tried configuring the RefreshScope as bean and using scope="refresh" but could see that the beans are not reflected with new values after peforming /refresh endpoint (from actuator)

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: the core problem is that what is the best way to create a "refreshable" beans in XML (equivalent of @RefreshScope annotation).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in other answers 'refresh' scope is just another scope. However there's an issue where the bean properties are not updated with new values after /refresh call - if you define and inject properties in XML. More on the issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/207). However the bean (i.e. actually the proxy) is instantiated after each /refresh call - but you need "*aop:scoped-proxy*" config since bean to which you inject the 'refresh' scoped bean, could be on a different scope. i.e.

```
<bean name="xmlValueBean" class="me.fahimfarook.xml.XMLValueBean" scope="refresh">
    <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to use @RefreshScope in core Spring(also Spring MVC) as people already pointed out, you have to implement the scope yourself also.

I also had the same dilemma and I did, I also wrote a blog about it, you can find there all the implementation details.

You can also use Spring Boot Configuration Server with your Spring MVC application, if you like to.

[@RefreshScope for Spring MVC](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2017/05/29/configuration-client-and-refreshscope-for-plain-spring-and-spring-boot-configuration-server/)

Answer (score -1):

@RefreshScope is just another scope. Look at how the [RefreshScope](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/refresh/RefreshScope.java) class is implemented. It is creating a new scope named "refresh".

That means you should be able to use the new scope in your XML configuration, like this.

```
<bean id = "..." class = "..." scope = "refresh">
</bean>
```

Comment: using scope="refresh" throws  java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'